# Centering floated block elements width different widths

Tags: css

Good Day.

Currently, my code works fine, except that the elements(images) align left (because of the float) and not center. How do i do it without altering the current stability of my hover function (nothing overflows) and by not using display: inline-block(not IE friendly) ?

HTML:

```
<div id="customers">
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1180" alt="absa" src="" /></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1178" alt="kumba" src=""/></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1176" alt="samancor" src=""/></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1179" alt="bosch" src="" /></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1185" alt="" src="" /></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1187" alt="DBSA" src="" /></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1190" alt="dac" src=""/></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1191" alt="eaton" src="" /></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1192" alt="megaphone" src="" /></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1193" alt="eazi" src=""/></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1194" alt="smss" src="" /></a>
 <a href=""><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1195" alt="partyat" src="" /></a> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#customers a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
}
#customers a img {
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 400ms linear;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
}
#customers a img:hover {
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 30px 30px -25px #acacac;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 30px 30px -25px #acacac;
    box-shadow: 0px 30px 30px -25px #acacac;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/fL5Gh/13/

Comment: a float is not supposed to center

Comment: yeah I know that, but how do I center it then?

Comment: why are you trying to center a floated image? if you're trying to center an image/div/whatever, then dont float it.

Comment: just remove your `float:left` and your images are all centered.

Comment: yes, I can do that, but then I cannot add heights and widths to the anchor parent elements...see the hover effect now: the 'rows' in which the images are contained are not fixed anymore, and content is being shifted down: http://jsfiddle.net/fL5Gh/24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to place each image inside its own div and align that div center inside your wrapper div. or use ul and li and inline them and center that text. Either way I see your current method as un-workable

Comment: Now I wouldn't mind typing up a solution if you would look into changing your method.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fL5Gh/26/ let me know if this is what your looking for. I decided to look at your css first. I mean I understand the centering of the images, got it. That's done by removing the float. Now you don't want the overflow so add padding to the bottom in as many px as you need based on your transition. Now if thats not what your looking for, and you want them in the inline style like your first jsfiddle (horizontal not vertical) than thats a different story. Please inform me.

Comment: Or you remove auto from width and set a width of each "a" like so: http://jsfiddle.net/fL5Gh/27/

Comment: yeah thank you, but it still aligns left. i think best solution is your first one, but I would rather remove the float and display the images and their a tags as inline, that way I will be able to center it. Then I would just add inline block to the a-tags and give them fixed heights and auto widths